# I can't upload more than One photo when I ask a question

Tags: bug, ios-app

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 5s (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B150)

Comment: By chance, did you already have a link in the question?

Comment: What rep do you have on the site where you tried to add an image?

Comment: I don't know if he was a "rep" or not, but "tester 101" was trying to help answer my question. We later and got referred to a chat room because the conversation was too long. This chat room conversation is still pending.

Comment: I already had one photo link in the question. That photo showed up. It is a photo of an old recepticle removed out of the wall but with the wires still hooked up to the receptacle.

Comment: Never mind, "rep" refers to reputation, not representative. When I click on my MJCallinall icon, I see a "46" a colored circle, and "4". I don't know if any of those are my reputation. I guess that it is the "46". Either way, I noticed that my rep has to be at least 100 in order to add more than one photo. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you need some amount of rep on the site where you're trying to upload more than one image. I can find most convenient information only for [Create Chat Rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) priviledge in the help:

> **What other new privileges in chat do I get?**
>   At 100 reputation you also get access to the "Upload image" button in chat.

Probably information about restiction for uploading an image to the post absent due to overlook. But also my search engine could break.